# Add filter for sources at product grid

Tags: magento2.3.1, multi-source-inventory

I'm running magento 2.3.1 with MSI and There's no filter,reports available based on sources.

Like, I would like to know which source has how many stock left or specific SKU has how many qty available in various sources.

How can I create filter for sources at products listing back end ?

Any ideas ? Maybe other possible solution will be helpful.

Comment: Hello, have you got any solution to this?

Comment: Nope yet. I ended up creating separate grid where I can manage SKUs and Source inventory.

Comment: Can you please share that module/code?